# Rapid generation advancement in Maize breeding

Tags: genetics, botany

Maize (Zea mays L.) is one of the important crops and its acreage is increasing considerably especially in Asia and Africa.  The common production system in tropical and subtropical climates is rain-fed. From the “Mendelian era” of nineteenth century we have now reached the stage of “Genomics era” in twenty-first century where several new tools and techniques are available to understand the genetics of traits and accelerate the breeding process. I want to induce early flowering in commericially grown Maize to reduce the life cycle of the crop. Any method to fast track the generations of the breeding cycle in Maize. Is Rapid generation advancement method established for Maize crop? It will help to reduce the normal crop life cycle which is 120-150 days to 60-70 days so that in 1 year 3 cycles of the crop can be grown.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you want, a 60-day generation for maize [has been established with some lines suitable for research](https://academic.oup.com/genetics/article/204/1/35/6066259) ("mini-maize"). I doubt that these lines are agronomically interesting, so if your goal is to breed these with the idea of developing germ plasm for production they may not be useful. If, however, your goal is to do research and determine variants useful for introduction into an agronomic background, then it may be useful. It looks like [there are related strains optimized for gene editing](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgeed.2020.622227/full).

If you are mostly just interested in traditional breeding in a fixed line, then there are a variety of [environmental conditions that can accelerate flowering in most plants](https://gpnmag.com/article/accelerating-growth-what-works-and-what-does-not/). The main issue is that these conditions may interfere with your phenotyping regimen or with desirable outcomes such as yield.

There is additionally [significant natural variation among maize types](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3316663/#bib18) (some [apparently with <60d flowering time](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-79418-1_3), which seems surprising to me). Possibly using one of those early-flowering cultivars as a starting point or founding parent could be interesting.